# Getting unexpected error when calling login api of JWT Authentication for WP-API in wp-engine

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wpengine

I am using react-wp-theme in wordpress the run a react app in wp-engine
I am trying to call JWT Authentication for WP-API Login api to authenticate the user it is giving success 200 response but in response data I am getting my index.php file content instead of token

It is working without any issue in local wordpress (running on xampp) when I promoted the code in wp-engine I am getting this issue

I have followed every steps mentioned plugin documentation

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secret-key');

define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
```

Error I am getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script
        src='/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/react-src/node_modules/@devloco/create- 
 react-wptheme-utils/wpThemeClient.js'>
    </script>

    <script
        src='/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/react-src/node_modules/@devloco/create-react-wptheme-utils/wpThemeErrorOverlay.js'>
    </script>

    <script>
        wpThemeClient.start("ws", "127.0.0.1", "8090"); 
    </script>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-wptheme" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" 
crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
    
    <title>Word Prev</title>
    <link href="/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/static/css/main.chunk.css? 
 76e963b2483ab6ad865c" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/static/js/bundle.js?76e963b2483ab6ad865c"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/static/js/0.chunk.js?76e963b2483ab6ad865c"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/wpn-react-wp-theme/static/js/main.chunk.js?76e963b2483ab6ad865c"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**API call from react-wp-theme**

```
axios.post('/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
  username: username,
  password: password,
})
.then((response) => {
  const token = response.data.token; 
  localStorage.setItem('token', token); 
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wpengine no longer supports configs in .htacess.

Talk to WPengine support and they will guide you to create web rules so that jwt works in WPengine.